# In a leaning position

Tags: meaning

> Don’t brake on the motorcycle in a leaning position .

1. Motorcycles lean while cornering and it can be dangerous to brake while the motorcycle leans. I wanted to make the sentence about this situation. What confuses me is that does people understand the leaning one is me or motorcycle? According to the sentence above what or who is in the leaning position?
2. If I change place of “on the motorcycle” to “in a leaning position” would the meaning change?

Comment: (By the way: unrelated to the question about language, but—I'm confused by the rule *not to brake when turning*! Isn't *some* braking always needed? Is the point "Don't brake *too* hard"? is it only "when leaning more than [a certain degree]"? (Since, on a bike, it's also impossible to turn without leaning to some degree.)

Comment: Two things: 1. "in a leaning position" is correct grammar, but unnatural. "While leaning" is better. 2. Unless you're a stunt rider, any time a motorcycle is leaning, it's turning, so describing the rule as "while turning" is the most natural.

Answer (score 2):

Context matters. If the surrounding context makes it clear, you can leave out information that would otherwise be necessary.

> Be careful. Don't drive too fast. Don't brake in a leaning position.

This *is* unclear, and could be understood as "don't brake when your body is leaning forward." The context is mixing various safety topics and doesn't explain more about "leaning."

> When cornering, the motorcycle may lean sideways. Traction is reduced when leaning like this. Don't brake while leaning.

In this passage, the context makes it clear that we're talking about the motorcycle leaning.

You ask whether your meaning could be made clearer by rearranging your sentence. No, but changing the wording a little might. If your context does *not* make it clear that you're talking about the motorcycle, not the rider, leaning, then you might need to say so. Your original example is:

> Don't brake on the motorcycle in a leaning position.

The phrase "on the motorcycle" is not helping the meaning much. Surely there is already enough context to know that we're talking about motorcycle riding. If you meant the phrase "brake on the motorcycle" to mean "apply the motorcycle's brakes," you need different wording. Instead, it would be understood as "Don't brake, [while you are] on the motorcycle..." which might be the source of your concern that "in a leaning position" could apply to the rider.

Instead, "Don't brake while the motorcycle is leaning" is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically (that is using general knowledge about motorbikes) we know that both the bike and you are leaning as you turn the bike.  Someone who has never seen a bike might not realise this, but most people know that you have to lean with the bike as you turn.

Idiomatically I'd suggest an alternative: "Don't brake while cornering".  You don't need to mention "on the motorbike" since that is probably clear from context. And you don't need to mention leaning, since the only time you lean the bike is when cornering.  "Corner" is a verb, meaning to turn a vehicle.